# Can we compress video in Ionic-1 + Angular-1 app before upload to s3 server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Does anybody know ,How we can do compression of video file in client side in hybrid application,
here i am building video application so the input file is too big like 150Mb  so need to do 60 to 70 Mb  before it going to server.

Comment: How are you procuring the video content? From camera, or from user gallery, or from somewhere else?

Comment: $cordovaCamera.getPicture gives me the device gallery video file but tried to compress  this  video file by VideoEditor.transcodeVideo cordova plugin but not success-ed yet because it is taking too much time for converting video or compression still looking easy tool for compress video file in frontend side!